# How do I install globally installed packages to virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I tried activating the venv and used path/to/venv/Scripts/python -m pip install requests to install it. However, it printed "Requirement already satisfied" because it was already installed globally. I tried copying the requests folder in site-packages as well, but pip freeze -l did not recognize it so I think it didn't work. How should I solve this?

Comment: You can still use the package if it's installed globally. Why do you want to install it under your venv a second time?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling globally then installing in the venv? Using the venv is best practice to avoid conflicts.

Comment: @JamesGeddes Yes, that was what I have been doing. I was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: are you using anaconda ? try `pip install -r <package name> -t <path-to-the-lib-directory>`

Comment: @sahasrara62 Unfortunately no.

Comment: How did you create the virtualenv? The normal mode without `--system-site-packages` should _not_ give you access to system-installed packages.